# Windows Phone (7+8) how to get a Popup Flyout style?

Tags: windows-phone-7, popup, transition, flyout, lostfocus

I've seen a Windows Phone 7 app with a window/popup which shows, after a use choice, half covering the current window, sliding in from the left while it closes when the users taps outside that window. For Windows 8x Store apps, this is a PopUp Control in a Flyout. But this is not available for Windows Phone.The regular pop-up control doesn't slide in with

```
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
```

which does work in a page-to-page transition. I have not succeeded either in closing it when I tap outside the pop-up. I tried adding `LostFocus="MyEndPopUp"` but that method is never called and also tried to end it on a `OnNavigateFrom`. What do I miss here?

If anyone could e.g. point me to some sample code doing more or less what I want would be great.

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of the app which uses it or the name of the app? Some open source controls maybe exist already which could work for you...

Comment: Even I am searching for something like that. Generally you can see this happening in Facebook App for Windows Phone 8